# Getting a word out of string of text in cell using wildcard and returning that text

Tags: excel, parsing, multiple-columns

I have a column with text in it that is formatted in the following way:

```
efo_ah-xxx-adv xxx_cluster xxx_admin usah1xxxxxxxx00:8099
```

I want to parse out the `usah1xxxxxxxx00` and return that value into a separate column on the same line.

***Here is the kicker (1/2):***

I have a mother load of these cells with those lines of text. All of them can have the string I want in different places. For example:

```
prod_ah-XX-Shared-Batch usahxxxxxxxxx00 0000 ProcessSubscriber
```

***Kicker (2/2)***

Not only the position of the criteria differs but also the `usahxxxxxxxxx00` can be different (the x's and 0's can represent anything). The only thing in common is that they can start with `usah` or `uspl`.

I have been searching how to get this done for the past 4-5 days and is driving me crazy. Every formula seems to be close but not close enough.

Comment: Is the length of the "usah..........." string ever 15 characters? Are there even more prefixes except "usah" and "uspl"?

Comment: Not enough info. Is it strictly starting with 'usah" and "uspl"? Is it always either of those followed by a certain number of characters? If it starts with "usah" or "uspl" and is not followed by a set number of characters, how do you determine where it ends? Please [edit] your question to include several rows of sample data, indicate what should (and should not) match from that data, and include what you've tried so far that isn't working so we'll know where to start.

Comment: Thanks for your replies.
@AxelRichter: only pre-fixes are usah & uspl / string is always 15 char with the last 2 being digits

Comment: @KenWhite: Yes, always starts with usah & uspl and is always 15 characters. I will edit and insert more data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your column is A and data starts in row1, I think this works for the cases you have mentioned:

```
=MID(A1,IFERROR(FIND("usah",A1),FIND("uspl",A1)),15)
```

and can be copied down.

Comment: This worked! Thank you so much! Do I need to mark this a s complete?

Answer (score 0):

This is a combination of the MID and FIND functions is my guess.  Without seeing the complete dataset or at least a sample containing all the cases it is hard to give a complete answer that would meet every case.  Could you post more sample cases?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately I don't have enough rep point to comment. :(